# Titanium Facebook Module 5.1.0 crashes at authorization

Tags: facebook, titanium, titanium-mobile, appcelerator-titanium, titanium-modules

I am getting a Facebook module crash when I try to authorize the Facebook module. I keep looking over the code but I can't seem to find an error. I follow the [Appcelerator guide](https://docs.appcelerator.com/platform/latest/#!/api/Modules.Facebook-method-authorize)  Anyone sees any errors? Thanks in advance.

Error from the console

```
[ERROR] :  The application has crashed with an uncaught exception 'InvalidOperationException'.
[ERROR] :  Reason:
[ERROR] :  fbauth2 is missing from your Info.plist under LSApplicationQueriesSchemes and is required for iOS 9.0
```

This is the facebook code in my index.js

```
var fb = require('facebook');
 fb.setLoginBehavior(fb.LOGIN_BEHAVIOR_NATIVE);
 fb.permissions = ["public_profile","email"];
 fb.authorize();
```

This is the ios section of the Tiapp.xml

```
 <ios>
    <enable-launch-screen-storyboard>true</enable-launch-screen-storyboard>
    <default-background-color>#3AB6ED</default-background-color>
    <plist>
        <dict>
            <key>CFBundleURLTypes</key>
            <array>
                <dict>
                    <key>CFBundleURLSchemes</key>
                    <array>
                        <string>fb55458225139xxxx</string>
                    </array>
                </dict>
            </array>
            <key>FacebookAppID</key>
            <string>55458225139xxxx</string>
            <key>FacebookDisplayName</key>
            <string>Fluid - Borrow it</string>
            <key>UISupportedInterfaceOrientations~iphone</key>
            <array>
                <string>UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait</string>
            </array>
            <key>UISupportedInterfaceOrientations~ipad</key>
            <array>
                <string>UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait</string>
            </array>
            <key>UIRequiresPersistentWiFi</key>
            <false/>
            <key>UIPrerenderedIcon</key>
            <false/>
            <key>UIStatusBarHidden</key>
            <false/>
            <key>UIStatusBarStyle</key>
            <string>UIStatusBarStyleLightContent</string>
            <key>NSLocationWhenInUseUsageDescription</key>
            <string>
                Using the user location to determine the neighborhood they are in to lend and borrow items.
            </string>
            <key>NSAppTransportSecurity</key>
            <dict>
                <key>NSAllowsArbitraryLoads</key>
                <true/>
                <key>NSExceptionDomains</key>
                <dict>
                    <key>facebook.com</key>
                        <dict>
                            <key>NSIncludesSubdomains</key> 
                            <true/>        
                            <key>NSExceptionRequiresForwardSecrecy</key> 
                            <false/>
                        </dict>
                    <key>fbcdn.net</key>
                        <dict>
                            <key>NSIncludesSubdomains</key> 
                            <true/>
                            <key>NSExceptionRequiresForwardSecrecy</key>  
                            <false/>
                        </dict>
                    <key>akamaihd.net</key>
                        <dict>
                            <key>NSIncludesSubdomains</key> 
                            <true/>
                            <key>NSExceptionRequiresForwardSecrecy</key> 
                            <false/>
                        </dict>
                </dict>
            </dict>
        </dict>
    </plist>
</ios>
```

Answer (score 0):

Apparently this was missing. The documentation is not very clear on making this required for Authorization as well.

```
<key>LSApplicationQueriesSchemes</key>
<array>
    <string>fbapi</string>
    <string>fb-messenger-api</string>
    <string>fbauth2</string>
    <string>fbshareextension</string>
</array>
```

Answer (score 0):

You are missing LSApplicationQueriesSchemes at your tiapp.xml.
Documentation says about these strings:

```
<key>LSApplicationQueriesSchemes</key>
<array>
    <string>fbapi</string>
    <string>fb-messenger-api</string>
    <string>fbauth2</string>
    <string>fbshareextension</string>
</array>
```

but if you will still facing problems with logging/receiving userdata on some devices try to add all strings (as Facebook SDK suggest):

```
<string>fbapi</string>
<string>fbapi20130214</string>
<string>fbapi20130410</string>
<string>fbapi20130702</string>
<string>fbapi20131010</string>
<string>fbapi20131219</string>
<string>fbapi20140410</string>
<string>fbapi20140116</string>
<string>fbapi20150313</string>
<string>fbapi20150629</string>
<string>fbapi20160328</string>
<string>fbauth</string>
<string>fbauth2</string>
<string>fb-messenger-api20140430</string>
```